# How can I create diagonal boxes

Tags: html, css

I´m developing an space for my webpage where I want some diagonal shaped boxes, like the ones on https://mkbhd.com/ where he inserted the studio channel link, podcast, etc. How can I develop something like this?

[image]

Comment: How you tried inspecting the buttons to see how it's done?

Comment: Hint: Look for [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

Comment: @Amadan, I think [`skew`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew) helps

Comment: @GeekyQuentin `skew` would affect the text as well, unless you specifically counteract it (or overlay a skewed box under a non-skewed text). But also OP specifically asked how to get boxes like in the linked webpage; the linked webpage used `clip-path`.

Comment: @Amadan you just have to add an `after` element to the button and skew it there, [look at this](http://www.java2s.com/example/html-css/css-widget/change-button-shape-to-parallelogram.html)

Comment: So far I have tryed @StepUp ´s answer and works, but I´m interesed in adding at least 3 of these boxes one next to each other, separated by some margin between them for having space for the boxes to wide when hovering over them. How can I configure these boxes for them to appear next to each other? I already have the hover effect, but it is the inline position what I´m messing with now.

Comment: @DiegoManzanares, if the current answer has solved your question, consider accepting it and ask your query as a new question, do not ask questions in comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As mdn says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path):

> The clip-path CSS property creates a clipping region that sets what
> part of an element should be shown. Parts that are inside the region
> are shown, while those outside are hidden.

So let's use `clip-path` property:

```css
.foo-bar {  
  width: 8rem;
  font-size: 12px;  
  background: lightgreen;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 7px;  
  text-align: center;
  clip-path: polygon(15% 0%, 100% 0, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
 <div class="foo-bar">Some text</div>
```

Comment: ``150deg`` LGTM.